# Why does my curl command fail when run through applescript but work fine when I run directly in a terminal?

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line

I am trying to write an applescript to control an installed projector using it's built in web interface. I have a curl command that pings the appropriate URL and can controll the projector as needed from the command line, when I build this into an applescript (required by my show control software) I

My applescript currently looks like this:

```
set theUrl to "http://192.168.0.103/cgi-bin/proj_ctl.cgi?key=shutter_on&lang=e&osd=on"
set theUsername to "dispadmin" -- set this to the username for the projector
set thePassword to "password" --set this to the password for the projector

set myFile to (POSIX path of (path to temporary items)) & "curl_downloaded_file.xml"

set curlScript to "/usr/bin/curl --connect-timeout 1 --anyauth --user" & " " & theUsername & ":" & thePassword & " -L " & theUrl & " -o " & myFile

display dialog "my variable: " & curlScript

do shell script curlScript
```

The `display dialog` line is for debugging to show what the curl command will look like, when I run this I get the following:

```
/usr/bin/curl --connect-timeout 1 --anyauth --user dispadmin:password -L http://192.168.0.103/cgi-bin/proj_ctl.cgi?key=shutter_on&lang=e&osd=on -o /private/var/folders/zs/f1hpkd2x281fvzyh4zd5dpcw0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/curl_downloaded_file.xml
```

Which seems correct. If I add quote marks around the URL I can run this command in the terminal with no issues and get the desired effect, however the Applescript will then continue to spit out the following error:

```
error "sh: -o: command not found
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   350  100   350    0     0  38888      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 38888

100   267    0   267    0     0   5235      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5235" number 127
```

This looks like curl is running but it doesn't hit the projector's web server to trigger the controll, also the `error "sh: -o: command not found` makes me think that the command isn't being parsed/passed correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you try putting the URL in quotes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While

```
http://192.168.0.103/cgi-bin/proj_ctl.cgi?key=shutter_on&lang=e&osd=on
```

works fine in a *browser*, it does not in a *shell*.

To resolve the issue you need to quote the **URL**.

In `set curlScript to ...` change `theUrl` to either `theUrl's quoted form` or: `quoted form of theUrl`